# is It necessary to install all update of skyrim or only need last of them?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

For improving game and also solving bug's:

Is it necessary to install **all updates** for Skyrim sequentially? Or do I only need **the last of them**?

Answer (score 4):

Skyrim's updates add bug fixes and some minor additional content (Bow and Spell Kill cams, and soon, mounted combat!).

While the game is certainly *playable* without the patches, there's no real reason not to get them.

If you're playing on the PC, Steam will even download the patches automatically for you, so "installing every patch" should be a non-issue. (There'll be only the one patch, regardless of how behind your client might be)

Comment: And if you're not playing on steam, you can get official patches [here](http://store.steampowered.com/agecheck/app/72850/).

Answer (score 2):

You should install everything. One update may not have the same content as another, and you would miss what you haven't installed.

Comment: Are you sure! I only have version 1.5.23, update patch . is it enough?